# Badge Suggestion: 'Helpful'

Tags: feature-request, badges, accepted-answer, badge-request

I am always a little hesitant to make a suggestion for badges but I thought this one might be interesting and there are so few badges based on accepted answers. I couldn't find any similar suggestions:

> Awarded for having 100 accepted answer from 100 unique users with a rep of at least 50.
>
> - bronze: 100 answers / 100 users
> - silver: 200 answers / 200 users
> - gold: 500 answers / 500 users

Name and values probably should be adjusted...

Comment: Why does it have to be unique users and 50 rep?

Comment: @M.Sameer to avoid gaming.

Comment: Needs more unicorn.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This proposal helps encourage desired behaviour - answering questions with quality answers to many different users.

- Quality of askers. Requiring the asker have 50 rep means it can't be gamed with fake/dummy/throwaway accounts. Sure, this could be modified either way to rep thresholds of 25 or 100.
- Quantity of askers. The 'unique askers' attribute means you've helped a lot of different people. It also ensures the badge can't be gamed by 2 people.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm. It seems to me that badges should recognise the things that reputation points don't, and vice versa. We use points to recognise the manufacture of good questions and answers, and badges to recognise good behaviour. Having a badge for something which also earns points seems redundant. More than that - it's spoiling people: helpful people already have high reputations; they don't need badges as well.

That's why the 'Unsung Hero' or whatever it is badge is a good idea: it recognises people who produce answers good enough to accept, but who don't get upvotes on them.

Comment: "Having a badge for something which also earns points seems redundant." How do you account for `Nice Answer` and related answer / question badges? They are based purely off of getting votes so based on your line of of thought, those should not exist either I guess?

Comment: Yup, pretty much. The argument against my bonfire of the badges is that they can represent different *Ways* of picking up rep: a badge for one answer which gets tons of upvotes, another for tons of answers which get a few upvotes each. But i'd still incinerate 'em.

Comment: Voting/reputation are intertwined with badges. I don't see how voting is not orthoganal to badges. It appears 3/4 are voting/rep related. Rep is meant to show your standing in the community; badges are fun add-ons to encourage behaviour (origins in Xbox Live obviously).